# Rails: Resque parellel queues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, resque

I have multiple jobs running in multiple queues with Resque. My problem is that when one queue is running lots of jobs, it holds up my other queues.

How can I get Resque to run parallel queues but still limit each queue to one job at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can launch different workers for each of your queue.

In order to do this you have to specify the name of the queue to process on the QUEUE env variable.

So if you have 3 queues you'd do the following:

- QUEUE=queue1 bundle exec rake resque:work
- QUEUE=queue2 bundle exec rake resque:work
- QUEUE=queue3 bundle exec rake resque:work

Comment: If I do this, I'll have to do the same for all my workers, right? Also, any documentation on this for further reading?

Comment: Yes, you're right. In my opinion it would be better to then specify queue names for each worker. You can specify multiple queues in the QUEUE var and resque will check queue in the same order you specified them. You can read more on the Resque README https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/1-x-stable/README.markdown#priorities-and-queue-lists (I suppose you're using version 1.x). Notice that using QUEUE=* queues are processed in alphabetic order.